# Magento2 How to solve 505 internal error while saving migrated customer from admin

Tags: magento2, customer, migration, data-migration

I migrated my magento 1 store to magento2 and all customer and other data are migrated successfully.
but when i try to save customer from admin , the page is redirect to 505 internal error.
if i create new customer and save it than that works ok.

so can anyone suggest me how i can solve this issue

Comment: developer mode on or check log file??

Comment: @RkRathod developer mode is off , and it  opens a new page after 1 to 2 minutes loading and shows 500 internal server error

Comment: enable developer mode and check and also check exception.log or system.log file